# need help to understand flaw in my program

Tags: c, file

I am programming in C and I start to do some basic programming like wordcount in files, but unfortunately I get flaw in my program's execution. The gcc compiler displays such a warning:

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:11: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘fopen’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
/usr/include/stdio.h:269: note: expected ‘const char * __restrict__’ but argument is of type ‘char’
```

Line 11 is the line with the if statement

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#define FAIL -1 
#define SUCCESS 1

int main (char *filename) {
    FILE *fp;
    char c;
    int wordcount = 0;
    if ((fp = fopen(*filename,"r")) == NULL)
        return FAIL;
    while (!feof(fp))
    {
        while(!isalpha(fgetc(fp)))
        {
            wordcount++;
        }
    }
    printf("wordcount: %d",wordcount);  
    fclose(fp);
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: `int main( int argc, char ** argv );`

Comment: Also, you are using `feof` incorrectly.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong

Comment: Also, main should return zero (or EXIST_SUCCESS) on success. (and EXIT_FAILURE ON failure)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The asterisk when applied before a pointer in C *dereferences* the pointer, i.e. it evaluates to whatever the pointer points at. You don't want that, you want:

```
if ((fp = fopen(filename,"r")) == NULL)
```

Otherwise you're passing a single character (the first character in `filename`) to `fopen()`, which expects a pointer to a 0-terminated array of characters (aka "a string").

Answer (score 0):

```
int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
  FILE *fp;
  char *path;
  path = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "default"
  fp = fopen( path, "r" );
  if( fp == NULL ) {
    perror( path );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
  }
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

`main` has to be declared as taking either no argument or `(int argc, char* argv[])`.  And it has to return an int in [0,255], typically either EXIT_SUCCESS or EXIT_FAILURE.

After that, enable warnings in your compiler (`gcc -Wall -Werror`) and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

By prefixing filename with a '*' you're passing the data filename points to rather than the address where the data is stored - should be:

```
if ((fp = fopen(filename,"r")) == NULL)
```

And main [only takes the arguments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_function) argc and argv. If you're passing the filename as the first argument on the command line, then:

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
   FILE *fp;
   char c;
   int wordcount = 0;
   if (argc<1) {
      fprintf(stderr, "need a filename");
      return FAIL;
   }
   if ((fp = fopen(argv[1],"r")) == NULL) {
   ....
```